# Alfresco: Restrict categories that can be selected

Tags: alfresco

I have a custom content type in Alfresco (3.3 Enterprise, if it matters) and I can assign one or more categories to that content. So far so good.

But can I restrict the set of possible categories to only a subset of all categories? If, for example, categories looked like below, **how can I restrict the user to only selecting a *region* subcategory** (e.g. Europe, South America, etc).

```
Categories
+ Software Document Classification   <- I do not want these to be picked.
|  + Utilisation Documents
|  + Software Descriptions
|  + ...
|
+ Regions                     <- I want to restrict the
|  + Latin America               user to this subset of categories.
|  + Europe
|  + ...
+ ...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the category root where users may start from via the "parentNodeRef" control-param on the category.ftl control. Simply find out the NodeRef for the category you wan to start from (the "Regions" node) and use that value for the "parentNodeRef" control-param.

Please see https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/change-root-element-category-picker-control for a similar question and the original answer. Also see https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Forms#category.ftl for an overview over the most important control-params for category.ftl.

Comment: Thank you, that's useful (I haven't yet got to the chapter in Jeff Pott's book on customising forms). Is there a way to specify this restriction via the model type XML? (e.g. in `config/alfresco/extension/model/somecoModel.xml`)

Comment: As you are working with the cm:generalclassifiable classification, there is no way to specify a root via the model XML. But if you define your own classification (own aspect similar to cm:generalclassifiable) and build up a hierarchy of categories for that, you can restrict the choice via the model XML - the choice of the classification aspect in itself is that restriction.
See http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Classification_And_Categories#Adding_your_own_classification for details.